Show that the SDE $dX_t = 3X_t^{1/3}dt + 3X_t^{2/3}dW_t, \quad X_0 = 0$ has infinitely many solutions
I have been trying to understand the solution to Problem 5 from this document. The problem is: Show that the SDE
$$dX_t = 3X_t^{1/3}dt + 3X_t^{2/3}dW_t, \quad X_0 = 0 \quad (1)$$
has strong existence, but not strong uniqueness. The provided solution claims that
$$X_t = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } t \leq T \\ (W_t - W_T)^3 & \text{if } t > T \end{cases}$$
is a solution to the SDE for any stopping time $T$ without explicitly show it. I've been trying to show that for any constant $T$, the process $X_t := f(W_t)$ is a solution to $(1)$, where I define the function $f(t, x) := (x - W_T) \mathbb{1}_{\{t > T\}}$, with Itô's formula. However, in order to apply Itô's formula, the function $f$ has to be twice continuously differentiable which is not the case here since $\lim_{t \to T^+}f(t, x) = (x - W_T)^3$ is not necessarily equal to $0$, meaning that $f$ is not even continuous in the first place. Is using Itô's formula the wrong approach to this problem?

The trick is to use the first principles definition of a solution to an SDE; $X_t$ solves the SDE if $X_t - X_0$ equals the integral from $0$ to $t$ of the right hand side. Plug in the solution form and show that this holds for all $t$.

Thanks for the advice! However, I'm still a bit stuck. Obviously, for $t \leq T$, $(W_t - W_T)^3 \mathbb{1}{{t > T}} = 0$ satisfies the SDE. However, for $t > T$ I get $$ (W_t - W_T)^3 = 3 \int_0^t (W_s - W_T)\mathbb{1}{{s > T}} ds + 3 \int_0^t (W_s - W_T)^2 \mathbb{1}_{{s > T}} dW_s,$$ and I'm not sure how to proceed. Since I'm not too comfortable with stochastic integrals, I might be missing something trivial.

Update: I have an idea how to proceed. Since the stochastic integral can be rewritten as the limit of a sum, we get \begin{align*} \int_0^t (W_s - W_T)^2 \mathbb{1}{{s > T}} dW_s &= \lim{n \to \infty} \sum_{j = 0}^{n-1} (W_{\frac{jt}{n}} - W_T)^2 \mathbb{1}{{\frac{jt}{n} > T}} (W{\frac{(j+1)t}{n}} - W_{\frac{jt}{n}} ) \ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j = \frac{Tn}{t}}^{n-1} (W_{\frac{jt}{n}}-W_T)^2 (W_{\frac{(j+1)t}{n}}-W_{\frac{jt}{n}} ) \ &= \int_T^t(W_s - W_T)^2 dW_s. \end{align*} Then, to show that the equality holds, we can apply Itô's formula to $(W_t- W_T)^3$ .
